# Angular JS - Running two functions in one controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm fairly new to AngularJS so apologies in advance.

```
var tcores = 0;

angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('search?idc=LH5&type=Virtual&cluster=1').success(function(data) {
      $scope.servers = data; // get data from json
      angular.forEach($scope.servers, function(item){
        //console.log(item.cores);
        if(parseInt(item.cores) != "NaN" && item.cores != "") {
          if(angular.isNumber(parseInt(item.cores))) {
            tcores = parseInt(tcores) + parseInt(item.cores);
          }
        }
      })
      console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 1 Total Cores: " + tcores);
    });
  }
]);

angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('search?idc=LH5&type=Virtual&cluster=2').success(function(data2) {
      $scope.serverscluster = data2; // get data from json
      angular.forEach($scope.serverscluster, function(item){
        //console.log(item.cores);
        if(parseInt(item.cores) != "NaN" && item.cores != "") {
          if(angular.isNumber(parseInt(item.cores))) {
            tcores = parseInt(tcores) + parseInt(item.cores);
          }
        }
      })
      console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 2 Total Cores: " + tcores);
    });
  }
]);
```

I'm trying to run both functions (both are pointed at different JSON outputs), however I am only receiving a response for "cluster 2".

Please advise how I can run both functions in the same module, ideally I will be running 8 of these requests on the same page so advice is most appreciated.#

Can you also tell my **why** only the bottom function is executing?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can't have two controllers with the same name you need to chain your `$http.get` in a unique controller name.

Comment: Thanks @Michelem - working now :) Please post as answer so I can give you the rep you deserve

Comment: I posted it with a working JSFiddle included. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote on a comment you have to chain the `$http.get` together and you must avoid duplicate controller names. Here is a simplified code:

```
angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http',

function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('search?idc=LH5&type=Virtual&cluster=1').then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        return $http.get('search?idc=LH5&type=Virtual&cluster=2');
    }).then(function(data2) {
        console.log(data2);
        $scope.serverscluster = data2; // get data from json
    });
}]);
```

And here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/7tez62qe/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to call your functions in single controller:

```
angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        var success = function(data) {
            $scope.servers = data; // get data from json
            angular.forEach($scope.servers, function(item){
                //console.log(item.cores);
                if(parseInt(item.cores) != "NaN" && item.cores != "") {
                    if(angular.isNumber(parseInt(item.cores))) {
                        tcores = parseInt(tcores) + parseInt(item.cores);
                    }
                }
            });
            console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 1 Total Cores: " + tcores);
        };

        var error = function(data) {
            console.log('Something went terrible wrong', data);
        };


        $http.get('search?idc=LH5&type=Virtual&cluster=1')
            .then(success, error);

        $http.get('search?idc=LH5&type=Virtual&cluster=2')
            .then(success, error);
    }
]);
```